# Библиография - это КНИГООПИСАНИЕ? Т. е. я описываю несколько книг - библиография готова?

Tags: недопустимая-метка

Автор выводит нас на страничку с описанием рекомендуемой им литературы для лучшего постижения Вечного города, как то:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> А. Н. Муравьев. «Римские письма». 1846. Почти приключенческий роман.
>   Эти «письма» к другу, полные впечатлений православного человека, в том
>   числе и о католической службе, были опубликованы. Однако
>   незамедлительно вызвали такие нападки со стороны униатов и католиков,
>   что автор почти сразу переиздаёт книгу, снабжая её обширным
>   комментарием. И до сих пор это произведение можно назвать одним из
>   лучших путеводителей для паломника по Вечному городу. Русский духовный
>   писатель, поэт, драматург, церковный и общественный деятель был забыт
>   почти на столетие. Его сочинения были малодоступны, и даже имя его
>   начинает упоминаться в советских научных изданиях только с середины
>   1960-х. Во время своих путешествий Андрей Николаевич собрал богатую
>   коллекцию икон и других реликвий веры, которую подарил Румянцевскому
>   музею (ныне коллекция находится в составе ГМИИ им. Пушкина).

И таких описаний десять штук. И шапку они имеют БИБЛИОГРАФИЯ.

А я хочу - ПРЕДЛАГАЕМАЯ ЛИТЕРАТУРА. Может, мне подскажут более точное название для такого книгоописания?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**ЛИТЕРАТУРА ПО ТЕМЕ** (если для шапки). В "БИБЛИОГРАФИИ" ничего особенно плохого нет: здесь имеет место "*аннотированная библиография*", в отличие от простого "списка литературы" (его тоже называют "библиографией" - он обозначает область написанного по теме, полную или неполную).